# Django channels websocket ValueError: No route found for path 'ws//'

Tags: python, django, websocket

I am currently trying to make a chat application using the Django channel tutorial as a base for the project. I am currently having a problem in which the WebSocket is disconnecting and Handshaking. I am new to Django and WebSocket.
chat/routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

chat/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('chat.urls')),  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("auth/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

chat/consumers.py

```
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .models import Room, Message 

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.room_name = None
        self.room_group_name = None
        self.room = None
        self.user = None 

    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = self.room_name
        self.room = Room.objects.get(name=self.room_name)
        self.user = self.scope['user']  

        # connection has to be accepted
        self.accept()

        # join the room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            # send the join event to the room
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'user_join',
                    'user': self.user.username,
                }
            )
            self.room.online.add(self.user)


    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
        # send the leave event to the room
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'user_leave',
                    'user': self.user.username,
                }
            )
            self.room.online.remove(self.user)

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        if not self.user.is_authenticated:  
            return                          

        # send chat message event to the room
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'user': self.user.username,  
                'message': message,
            }
        )
        Message.objects.create(user=self.user, room=self.room, content=message)  

    def chat_message(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))

    def user_join(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))

    def user_leave(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
```

mysite/asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack 
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  'http': get_asgi_application(),
  'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(  
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ), 
})
```

chat/static/room.js

```
const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('roomName').textContent);
let chatLog = document.querySelector("#chatLog");
let chatMessageInput = document.querySelector("#chatMessageInput");
let chatMessageSend = document.querySelector("#chatMessageSend");
let onlineUsersSelector = document.querySelector("#onlineUsersSelector");

// adds a new option to 'onlineUsersSelector'
function onlineUsersSelectorAdd(value) {
    if (document.querySelector("option[value='" + value + "']")) return;
    let newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = value;
    newOption.innerHTML = value;
    onlineUsersSelector.appendChild(newOption);
}

// removes an option from 'onlineUsersSelector'
function onlineUsersSelectorRemove(value) {
    let oldOption = document.querySelector("option[value='" + value + "']");
    if (oldOption !== null) oldOption.remove();
}

// focus 'chatMessageInput' when user opens the page
chatMessageInput.focus();

// submit if the user presses the enter key
chatMessageInput.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter key
        chatMessageSend.click();
    }
};

// clear the 'chatMessageInput' and forward the message
chatMessageSend.onclick = function() {
    if (chatMessageInput.value.length === 0) return;
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "message": chatMessageInput.value,
    }));
    chatMessageInput.value = "";
};

let chatSocket = null;

function connect() {
    chatSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws/" + roomName + "/");

    chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the WebSocket.");
    }

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log("WebSocket connection closed unexpectedly. Trying to reconnect in 2s...");
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Reconnecting...");
            connect();
        }, 2000);
    };

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data);

        switch (data.type) {
            case "chat_message":
                chatLog.value += data.user + ": " + data.message + "\n";
                break;
            case "user_join":
                chatLog.value += data.user + " joined the room.\n";
                onlineUsersSelectorAdd(data.user);
                break;
            case "user_leave":
                chatLog.value += data.user + " left the room.\n";
                onlineUsersSelectorRemove(data.user);
                break;
            default:
                console.error("Unknown message type!");
                break;
        }

        // scroll 'chatLog' to the bottom
        chatLog.scrollTop = chatLog.scrollHeight;
    };

    chatSocket.onerror = function(err) {
        console.log("WebSocket encountered an error: " + err.message);
        console.log("Closing the socket.");
        chatSocket.close();
    }
}
connect();
```

The error produced:

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws// [127.0.0.1:62654]
Exception inside application: No route found for path 'ws//'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 168, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws//'.
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws// [127.0.0.1:62654]
```

I am pretty sure I have to change the syntax of the websocket_urlpatterns in routing.py but am not sure how to approach it. Will appreciate it if there is a link or a place I can find since I was unable to google anything.

Comment: In your JS `roomName` is an empty string so you generate the path `/ws//`, you need to get the correct value or handle when it's empty

Comment: Thank you it was not giving me the error when I changed the roomName to not be a empty string